# The bird with the ball

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

An evil bird snatched the ball but the people burst in laughter.

An angry devil tried to kill the bird but the bird never died.

*Who is this crazy bird?*

Hint 1:

> Once upon a time, a bat fought with this bird.

Hint 2:

> 2 0 1 9 ball.

Hint 3:

> That ball looked like the world.

Hint 4 [added after 2 days]:

> I am still here, the bird says. You were never really here gladiator.

Hint 5 [final hint]:

> The bird has a message for you: Why so serious?

Comment: Does this have anything to do with rot13(pbivqavargrra)?

Comment: @mestackoverflow no

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crazy bird is:

> **Joaquin Phoenix** who played in **The Joker**

An evil bird snatched the ball but the people burst in laughter.

> Phoenix won the Golden Globe for the Joker (an evil character) - people laughed during his acceptance speech.

An angry devil tried to kill the bird but the bird never died.

> Batman (bat = devil?) and the Joker are enemies that fight one another

Who is this crazy bird?

> A **Phoenix** is a kind of bird

Hint #1:

> **Batman** fought with **The Joker**

Hint #2:

> **The Joker** was released in 2019

Hint #3:

> **Golden globe** that Phoenix won

Hint #4:

> Joaquin Phoenix also played in **The Gladiator (2000)** and **I'm Still Here (2010)** and **You Were Never Really Here (2017)**

Hint #5:

> **Why so serious?** is a common line said by **the Joker**, played by Joaquin Phoenix in the 2019 film by this name